How can I solve error invalid or unexpected token error in NPM
npm error Invalid or unexpected token
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-31T14_56_24_134Z-debug-0.log

I am getting such an error when I try to run npm init -y in my terminal which is saying that the NPM error invalid or unexpected token. I am also getting such an error when I try to run any NPM cmd in terminal

Check your ~/.npmrc for unexpected characters, try npm cache clean --force, and/or ensure PATH environment includes a path to nodejs. See if the issue still persists in a different terminal/shell as well. Also, what is your node -v & npm -v?
